# /etc/default/grub syntax error

Tags: grub2

How can I add kernel parameters with whitespaces to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`? For example when I do:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_os_name=\"Microsoft Windows XP\""
```

followed by

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I get the following `linux`-line in grub.cfg:

```
linux /vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=<long id> rw quiet acpi_os_name="Microsoft Windows XP"
```

If I boot with this grub.cfg, I get the following output during the boot process:

```
/init: eval: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
```

If I remove `acpi_os_name=\"Microsoft Windows XP\"` everything works as before. However the reason, I'm doing this, is an acpi fan problem with my notebook. So I'm following this article in order to make the fan work:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DSDT

**Edit 0:**

The output of `uname -s -r -v` is:

```
Linux 3.13.8-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 1 12:19:51 CEST 2014
```

Comment: Is it possible that you didn't recreate your initramfs image?

Comment: @pavel-imerda I pressed the button `e`, when the grub menu showed up and temporarily edited out the acpi_os_name-line in order to boot into the root-account. After that I executed `mkinitcpio -p linux` and rebooted. However I still get the same syntax error.

Comment: Then it sounds like a problem in the init. I heard that Archlinux is using systemd, nowadays, so many things may have stopped working.

Comment: It looks most likely that the comment above is correct and that this is a `systemd` problem - probably it is trying to parse the kernel options somewhere along the line and has a bug in doing so. It may also be a problem with the way that the kernel parses the options and passes various parameters to `init`, but this seems less likely.

Answer (score 3):

This is/was a documented bug in GRUB2. There are reports on:

- Ubuntu   - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/445952
- Debian   - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=550319
- Upstream - http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?27641

The serious associated issue seems to have been that even if you got the quotes to appear on GRUB's claimed kernel command line, they were not honoured. However this issue appears to have now been fixed upstream and now all that remains is the overuse of quote stripping here documents in the shell code which generates the `grub.cfg` file.

It should work if you do:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_os_name=\\\"Microsoft Windows XP\\\""
```

Or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet acpi_os_name=\"Microsoft Windows XP\"'
```

#### Update

The extra quoting shouldn't be required from at least GRUB 2.00 and above, the problem above does not appear to be GRUB related.

Comment: Thanks for the links but it doesn't seem to work. When I try the first option, I get the following output: `/init: eval: line 1: XP"=y: not found` . The second option gives the same error. However in both cases the error isn't fatal and the system boots up.

Comment: @ChristopherSchmidt, which version of GRUB2?

Comment: I use GNU GRUB Version 2.02~beta2. However even though it's a beta version this seems to be the "official" version, Archlinux uses right now. I didn't install it on my own initiative. I just used `pacman -Syyu` and got it installed at some point.

Comment: @ChristopherSchmidt, what line appears in `grub.cfg` in both cases? Maybe this is more to do with the kernel than anything else. Also, what is the output of `dmesg | grep "Command line"` after boot?

Comment: In both cases the line is: `linux /vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=<really long id> rw quiet acpi_os_name=\"Microsoft Windows XP\"` . And the output of `dmesg | grep "Command line"` after boot is: `[   0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=<really long id> rw quiet acpi_os_name=\"Microsoft Windows XP\"` .

Comment: @ChristopherSchmidt, I should mention that it is better to add this information to your question. But it appears that your initial attempt in the question is the correct way to do add the option and that this is a kernel issue. What kernel version do you have? Also, if for whatever reason there are quoting/escape characters in or around your UUID this could also cause the problem (although I don't see why there would be).

Comment: I edited my original question. Now it includes the output of `uname`. Also there are no special characters or quoting characters in or around the UUID.